# When MongoDB DBRef lazyness is set to true, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is throw

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following class:

```
@Document(collection = "T_FOO")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @Field
    private String name;

    @Field
    private String observations;

    @DBRef
    @Field
    private Foo[] parents;

}
```

Which succeeds in this test:

```
@Test
    public void testFooWithParents() throws Exception {
        //mock User
        User user = new User(); user.setLogin("admin");
        when(userService.getUserWithAuthorities()).thenReturn(user);

        // Create Father
        restFooMockMvc.perform(post("/app/rest/foos")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJson(fooFather)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        // Create Mother
        restFooMockMvc.perform(post("/app/rest/foos")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJson(fooMother)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        foo.setParents(new Foo[]{fooFather, fooMother});

        // Create Foo
        restFooMockMvc.perform(post("/app/rest/foos")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJson(foo)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        // Read Foo
        MvcResult result = restFooMockMvc.perform(get("/app/rest/foos/{id}", DEFAULT_ID))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(DEFAULT_ID))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(DEFAULT_NAME.toString()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.observations").value(DEFAULT_OBSERVATIONS))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.parents[0].id").value(FATHER_ID))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.parents[1].id").value(MOTHER_ID))
                .andReturn();

        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    }
```

When I set the parents array as `lazy = true`, I'm getting this exception:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  
Cannot subclass final class class [Lorg.domain.Foo;
```

This is thrown in the moment I request the Foo son ("Read Foo"). What is happening that Spring cannot re-build the objects again?

Best,
Pedro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lazy loading Db-Refs in Spring Data MongoDB is only supported if the type of the property is a non final class or interface since we need to be able to create a JDK or CGLib Proxy for it. Arrays are not supported. I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1157 to track this.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and the bug Thomas. I cannot test right now but if I replace for a `List<Foo>` my array it should work them?

Comment: Yes using a collection class / interface should work.

Comment: I does indeed. Thanks for the help!